# Exact Direction of Prayer

Tags: shemoneh-esrei

I saw an article of Rabbi Itzkowitz (?) on the web 6 years ago about whether one should face Jerusalem in the precise direction as on the compass, or the shortest direction by travel, as the planes fly.  Could you find this article for me?

Comment: Googled. http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3502321/jewish/Why-Do-We-Face-East-When-Praying-Or-Do-We.htm ?

Comment: what is unclear about the question?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably thinking of [this](https://www.myzmanim.com/read/direction.aspx) article on Myzmanim.
The name provided there is R' Dovid Eisikowitz.